# Python Flask get zip file from POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I have a flask Web service called from a postman or curl, the call isn't from a form, this is a direct call with a zip passed as parameter.
I have tryed with get_data() like this

```
file = request.get_data()
with zipfile.ZipFile(r'/my/path/myzip.zip', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file)
```

The zip is created but are empty, if i return file value like `return file`, i get bits data, so the data are here..

If i try with the `request.files` i need to pass a filestorage from a form, so now, i have no clue what i can do!

All i found on google are based on form request. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but if i get a Zip file from POST.. how i can save the zip inside a directory? I'm able to do it with form, but with only a POST.. i know the POST is working because when i use print(file) from the request i see the binary values

Answer (score 0):

With the little code you provided, I assume `get_data()` returns a string with your data. The issue you're having is `write()` is used to write a file into the zip using its path NOT raw data. Try using `writestr()` instead. Here's the relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr

Comment: Thanks, in fact, the POST come from oracle and content are blob format. the blob is a zip file when i ```print(file, file=sys.stdout)``` i see the content in byte or binary or blob format.

Comment: It will work with bytes too. If it works please consider accepting the answer !

Comment: thanks but it's not working! I got an error 500 again, with the same error : content empty

Comment: How do you use the method ? It should look like: `f.writestr('filename_in_the_archive', data)`

Comment: Yes, i've tryed what the doc say! what it say are the content is empty. The zip are generated via oracle, maybe thats the problem, we are looking on that!